# how to represent "sub-sequences" in uml sequence diagrams?

Tags: uml

In activity diagrams, you can have a top level activity diagram that contains a sub-activity diagram.  This is useful where the sub-activity contains lots of details that you don't want to show in the top level activity diagram.

Is a similar concept available for sequence diagrams?

Basically, I have a sequence diagram where I want to hide some of the details in the diagram by moving those details to another sequence diagram.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a `<<ref>>` fragment in your sequence diagram, that references a sub sequence diagram.

See for example this picture : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/feb04/3101_figure11.jpg where Balance Lookup and Debit Account are references to other sequence diageams that may in turn contain plenty of lifelines and calls.

Comment: the link is dead, archive.org still has it: https://web.archive.org/web/20131228124850/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/feb04/3101_figure11.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it looks like the solution may be to use an [Interaction Overview Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_overview_diagram).

Comment: You might, but these are not often used. See my answer for a more common solution. The <<ref>> fragment I mention there is, in fact, the same as in the Interaction Overview Diagram.