# Have I to make Sequence Diagrams for all methods in application?

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram

I would like to create some sequence diagrams to help explain different parts of my system but it is difficult to represent a significant part of the system if I have to include every single loop and method that the code will run through during the process in the real application.

Is it ok to omit some of these details in order to capture more of the system but at a slightly higher level?

I am inexperienced with these types of diagrams but would like to improve my knowledge in this area.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to display every method that makes up your unit of work but you can always split it up into smaller units of work that form the big part and refer to them. If you find it impossible to extract these smaller units then that might be an indication your design isn't all that great.

Comment: Do whatever you want with the tool that is UML. The goal is to have a diagram that is as helpful as possible, not a diagram that is as realistic and exhaustive as possible. UML is just a documentation tool. You should drive the tool, not the reverse.

Comment: +1 @JBNizet. OP: Ask yourself why you are creating these diagrams. Who is the intended audience, what information are you trying to convey, and what do you hope a reader would get out of them? How can they be helpful? Think about your goal in creating the diagrams, and let *that* determine the choices you make about what to include or exclude. If you are unsure about whether or not a specific piece of information should be included, ask yourself if it really needs to be there -- is it key to giving the reader the understanding that they need to complete the task they are trying to complete?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You should also consider using "sub-sequence" feature, how this is implemented may depend on the diagramming tool that you are using try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806853/how-to-represent-sub-sequences-in-uml-sequence-diagrams

Answer (score 0):

### No,

The targets of diagraming are: better understanding and readability of your concepts, and cheap preliminary testing of them. So, you needn't write diagrams for algorithms that are trivial and/or widely known, or are imported as a black box from some external resource.

Also, don't forget that for many programmers reading code is more easy than reading a sequence diagram. If you work in such team, making diagrams for lower level algorithms has no extra use in comparison to simply good commenting and structuring of the code.